# javascript hash keys hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript

In Javascript to find all the values in a hash I have seen the following code:

```
var myHash = {};
myHash['one'] = 1;
myHash['two'] = 2;
for (var key in myHash) {
    if (myHash.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

What is the point of having the hasOwnProperty check here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to make sure that `key` is a property defined directly on `myHash` and not one that was inherited through a prototype chain. Using `in` doesn't automatically filter out inherited properties, so you get to do it yourself.

But, as others have said, it isn't necessary for your particular example.

**Source:** [`hasOwnProperty` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Answer (score 0):

It may be more to the point if myHash is a new instance of an object with enumerable properties, so that methods and other inherited properties will not be listed.

Answer (score 0):

In that particular case there's no difference, but if myHash had "*inherited*" properties then those would be looped over too, without the hasOwnProperty check.

This is most likely a prevention thing, or even a copy-paste where the coder didn't worry about checking if every line was necessary, just that it worked.